# What is causing this character overlap during text rendering?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to display text with a texture and font description created with BMFont in OpenGL 3.3, but whenever I display the text there is some overlap between certain characters.

Here is the text at normal 1.0x scale:

[image: 1.0x scale]

As you can see, the 'e' in "Hello" overlaps the next 'l' a bit (with the same happening for the 'r' in "world") and the 'w' in "world" overlaps the 'o' quite a bit. Here is a 3.5x scale image to make the overlap a bit more apparent:

[image: 3.5x scale]

I was wondering if someone would be able to explain to me why this is occurring and, if possible, explain how to fix it.

My method for generating the vertex mesh is as follows: (C++)

```
// position control variables
const float tscalex = 1.0f / _font.GetTexture().GetSize().x;
const float tscaley = 1.0f / _font.GetTexture().GetSize().y;
const float hspace  = _font.FindGlyph( ' ' ).XAdvance;
const float vspace  = _font.GetInfo().LineHeight;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;

// generate a quad for each character
char pchar = 0;
for ( uint i = 0; i < _text.length(); ++i )
{
    // apply kerning
    char cchar = _text[ i ];
    x += _font.FindKerning( pchar, cchar );
    pchar = cchar;

    // handle special characters
    switch ( cchar )
    {
        case ' ':
            x += hspace;
            continue;
        case '\t':
            x += hspace * 4;
            continue;
        case '\n':
            y += vspace;
            x = 0.0f;
            continue;
    }

    // get the character's glyph
    const Font::Glyph& glyph = _font.FindGlyph( cchar );

    int width  = glyph.Width;
    int height = glyph.Height;
    int left   = glyph.X;
    int top    = glyph.Y;
    int right  = glyph.X + width;
    int bottom = glyph.Y + height;
    float yy   = y + glyph.YOffset;

    float u1 = float( left   ) * tscalex;
    float u2 = float( right  ) * tscalex;
    float v1 = float( top    ) * tscaley;
    float v2 = float( bottom ) * tscaley;

    // create the quad
    uint16 count = uint16( _mesh.Vertices.Size() );
    _mesh.Vertices.Add( Vertex( Vec3( x,         yy,          0 ) * _scale, Vec3(), Vec2( u1, v1 ) ) );
    _mesh.Vertices.Add( Vertex( Vec3( x,         yy + height, 0 ) * _scale, Vec3(), Vec2( u1, v2 ) ) );
    _mesh.Vertices.Add( Vertex( Vec3( x + width, yy + height, 0 ) * _scale, Vec3(), Vec2( u2, v2 ) ) );
    _mesh.Vertices.Add( Vertex( Vec3( x + width, yy,          0 ) * _scale, Vec3(), Vec2( u2, v1 ) ) );
    _mesh.Indices.Add( count + 0 );
    _mesh.Indices.Add( count + 1 );
    _mesh.Indices.Add( count + 2 );
    _mesh.Indices.Add( count + 2 );
    _mesh.Indices.Add( count + 3 );
    _mesh.Indices.Add( count + 0 );

    // advance
    x += glyph.XAdvance;
}
```

Comment: You either haven't enabled alpha blending, haven't loaded the alpha channel, or have set the depth comparison function to GL_LESS rather than the standard GL_LESS_EQUAL.

Comment: @Jason: Setting the depth function to GL_LEQUAL is what fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Why are you rendering 2d text with depth test enabled?

Comment: To be honest, turning it off didn't even occur to me.

Comment: Depth test is not necessary because the Z is always zero.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't you be adding the `XOffset` as well?

Comment: I know, but like I said I didn't think of it. And I could, but some characters are drawn slightly over others if I do. http://imgur.com/HE2oWGM The same thing happens with monospace fonts.

Comment: I actually think this overlap is caused by BMFont. I usually add a 1px padding between each char before exporting the texture. You can do that in the tool.

Comment: I have a 4px padding on each character.

Comment: You could just write into the pixel shader to clip alpha pixels. (Alpha Clipping) Blending would be better for most cases. But clipping is an alternate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the why comment:

> Per Jason:
>   You either haven't enabled alpha blending, haven't loaded the alpha
>   channel, or have set the depth comparison function to GL_LESS rather
>   than the standard GL_LESS_EQUAL.

Here is the "how to fix it" comment:

> Per fastinvsqrt:
>   Setting the depth function to `GL_LEQUAL` is what fixed it